# Cлучайно удалил модуль app из android studio

Tags: android-studio, android

Удалил модуль app, но давно не делал коммитов, что делать?

Comment: Не теряя времени, начать писать заново.

Comment: НА будущее, если что-то нечайно удалил сразу жмякай ctrl+z. Не раз спасало

Answer (score 1):

Если модель остался физически то подключить его заново.

Если удалили из диска то можно вернуть из Local History.